# MVC Custom Authorize Attribute behavior

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to build a custom `AuthorizeAttribute` for use in my MVC application. The tag will check the Users table, and see if the user is an administrator. Simple enough.

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.All, AllowMultiple=false, Inherited = true)]
public class AdminOnlyAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute {

    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext) {

        using (var db = new ArtContext()) {
            var user = db.Users
                .Where(x => x.UserId == httpContext.User.Identity.Name)
                .FirstOrDefault();

            if (user != null) 
                if (user.IsAdministrator)
                    return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

What is confusing me is that, even though the Home controller is not decorated with this attribute, it is still being invoked, and users are being prompted for a UID/PWD.

Is the tag executed when it's registered with the filter config? Is there a way I can prevent that from executing (seemingly) by itself?

**EDIT**

I had the filter registered globally. I thought all filters had to be registered before they could be used, so this whole thing was a lack of understanding on my part!

```
public class FilterConfig {
    public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters) {
        filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
        //filters.Add(new AdminOnlyAttribute());
    }
}
```

Comment: This would be significantly simpler if you just used Roles for what they're designed for.  Create an Administrator role, then use the standard Authorize attribute with the Administrator role parameter.  This will also perform much better since the standard authorize attribute doesn't do any database access.

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch it would be simplier, but we wanted to stay away from greating another active directory group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you register it as a global filter, it will apply everywhere on your site.  You can override it by decorating your controllers/methods with the `[AllowAnonymous]` attribute.

Comment: That was it! I thought any filters had to be registered before you could use them. This whole issue was my lack of understanding! I removed it from the global filter config and now it's working as expected.